# How to collect information from multiple siblings using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's the html Im working with:

```
<a 'data' = 'ubr_app'>List</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            'a'
        </li>
        <li>
            'b'
        </li>
        <li>
            'c'
        </li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            1
        </li>
        <li>
            2
        </li>
        <li>
            3
        </li>
```

I want to store all the information in those lists in separate arrays. What I have done in python is the following:

```
def getItems(soup):
    item1_list = []
    item2_list = []
    appliance = soup.find('a', {'data-lid' : 'ubr_app'})
    appliance_ul = appliance.parent.find_next_sibling() # go to 1st <ul> sibling
    for item in appliance_ul.find_all('li'):
        item1_list.append(item.text)

    appliance_ul = appliance_ul.find_next_sibling() # go to 2nd <ul> sibling
    for item in appliance_ul.find_all('li'):
        item2_list.append(item.text)
    return item1_list, item2_list
```

This gives me ['a','b','c'] and [1,2,3].
This does what I want to do, but it is very static and looks like ugly code. Is there a way to just search all existing 'ul' siblings so I can save the information in each nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `.find_next_sibling()`, use [`.find_next_siblings()` (plural)](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and give it a filter:

```
def getItems(soup):
    items = []
    appliance = soup.select('a[data-lid="ubr_app"]')[0]
    for appliance_ul in appliance.parent.find_next_siblings('ul'):
        items.append([i.text for i in appliance_ul.find_all('li')])
    return items
```

The `.find_next_siblings('ul')` call returns a list of all `<ul>` sibling tags.